# Build on travis failing for git submodule

Tags: angular, express, travis-ci, git-submodules

I have an angular project which has a git submodule for the backend.

It builds fine when i run it on my local machine. But, when i build it on travis it fails.

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/home/travis/build/faxad/cartify/backend/node_modules/raw-body/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Complete build log here.

https://travis-ci.org/faxad/cartify/builds/378869452

After taking a close look at travis logs, i found out that travis issues the following commands (which also throws the same error when i run them locally)

> git clone --branch=upgrade https://github.com/faxad/cartify.git
>   faxad/cartify
>
> git submodule update --init --recursive

However, the following seems to be working fine without any issues

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/faxad/cartify.git

Comment: Are you sure it's checking out all of the submodules? Without a [mcve] this question isn't answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to resolve the issue by first installing the dependencies of the submodule project and then for the project itself.